# XWiki insert text into a page

Tags: groovy, xwiki

Does anyone know the best way to insert some text into an XWiki document preferably using Groovy (though Velocity will work, too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's quite easy to do. For example you can use $doc.setContent() in Velocity/Groovy.

If you need more details it would be great if you could send your questions to the XWiki mailing lists/forums at http://dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/MailingLists

Thanks
-Vincent